# Python 3 -- Module not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

I have the following file structure...

```
 > Boo
    > ---modA
    > ------__init__.py
    > ------fileAA.py
    > ---modB
    > ------__init__.py
    > ------fileBB.py
```

When inside fileBB.py I am doing

```
from modA.fileAA import <something>
```

I get the following error:

```
from modA.fileAA import <something>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modA'
```

Note that the `__init__.py` files are empty and using Python 3.

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is the Python script? If you are running `python3 fileBB.py` directly then it won't look up the tree for modules.

Comment: put `__init__.py` in Boo ?

Comment: Run it from within the Boo directory

Comment: I've used `sys.path.append('../')` before the import in this scenario and it has worked in the past.

Comment: tried to add __init__.py at Boo but the same error

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly a `PYTHONPATH` issue of where you're running your script from.  In general this works:

```
$ ls modA/
fileAA.py  __init__.py
$ cat modA/fileAA.py 
x = 1
$ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from modA.fileAA import x
>>> x
1
```

You can look at `sys.path` to inspect your path.

Answer (score 1):

```
main_package
├── __init__.py
├── modA
│   ├── fileAA.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── modB
    ├── fileBB.py
    └── __init__.py
```

Have an `__init__.py` in the root directory and then use import like

```
from main_package.modA.fileAA import something
```

Run using a `driver` file inside `main_package` then run, it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sys.path.append` worked for me. I inspected the paths of the version which imported the package correctly and added those paths to the kernel which I was working on which had the import error.
I had an issue with 2 packages, one working on anaconda and the other on Python3.7. Adding the Python3.7 paths to the anaconda kernel (Python 3) solved the issue.

I.e.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('...\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages\\win32')
```

Answer (score -1):

As you have written your code in `fileBB.py` and trying to import **variables/functions/classes** etc. defined in `fileAA.py`, you actually need to do something like this:

- First create an empty `__init__.py` inside **Boo**.
- Then try to import like this:

  ```
  from ..modA.fileAA import <something>
  ```

As per my experience with writing packages, it should work fine.

> **Note:** Please comment if it doesn't work, I will help but this should not happen.